# Magnetic rod in Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

How does thin magnetic rod suspended in uniform magnetic field oscillate? I want to know **what kind of oscillations** will they be (displacement will be angular or linear) and **which phenomenon** (what forces are involved) causes these oscillations? And why it has to be thin?

For example:

In a spring block system, SHM is carried out for small **linear displacements**. And this motion is due to **restoring forces of spring**.

Some formulations would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are missing something. Does it really need to be thin?

Comment: I think it may be a more complex phenomenon, I suggest to write more from it. It would be really unfortunate if your question would be closed as unclear, because it is interesting.

Comment: @Utkarsh I came across this question twice and the same was mentioned i.e.  it needs to be thin,  in both of them. I can attach a picture of that question, if required

Answer (score 1):

There will be a magnetic moment induced in the rod. For a small angle displacement from stable equilibrium, the torque $\tau=m\times B=mB*sin(\theta)\approx mB\theta$

This, when equated with the product of the rod's moment of inertia and angular acceleration will give a differential equation that shows that the rod will oscillate.

[image]

Comment: Like i asked does it really have to be thin ?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it should have to be thin, but there might be a reason that I don't see.